# Randomize distinct cout statements (like getting 4 possible answers for a quiz)

Tags: c++, arrays, random

This code is outputting 1 correct answer - which is always the one associated with 'random_number', so the first `cout` statement is always true. But who wants this kind of a quiz?

```
 srand((int)time(0));
            int random_number = rand() % max_event_number;
                std::cout <<"\n" << final_years[random_number] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\n" << final_years[1 + random_number] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\n" << final_years[2 + random_number] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\n" << final_years[3 + random_number] << std::endl;
                std::cout << "\n" << "Please type the correct year : " << std::endl;
```

Yes..., I can generate some random answers from the entire array, but they won't necessarily include the correct answer.

I don't want to change the way the correct answer is generated by the first 'random_number', because it takes only one line of code to check if the answer is true or not...

If only I could shuffle every time those 4 cout statement...

How would you do it?

Comment: So you want to use one true answer and three false answers and shuffle them? What keeps you from doing that? Read up on Fisher-Yates.

Comment: A `switch(random_number)` maybe?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mre].

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I'm getting 4 random numbers, which are perfectly fine, and one of them is always true. I just want to randomize the <<cout output if possible, because if the output is displayed line by line...  the random number will stay in a non-random position... :)

Comment: If `random_number` is the index of the correct answer, why not generate three other random values (with a check to ensure they are distinct) and then shuffle all four?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I want to shuffle the answers displayed on the screen. I don't know a method in which some cout statements can be displayed in a random order...

Comment: @peter Oh, I see. I think I can do that. I was fixating on a solution to randomize the cout ouput which already has random numbers inside. But I think I can randomize once more the random numbers. :)

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase closer to yout shown code. You want to fill an array of four ints with the numbers 0,1,2,3 and shuffle them. Then use them in your code instead of directly the digits.

Comment: @AlexPina Why not having an array of four strings indexed by your random numbers, and "`cout`" these in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>  
    
    std::vector<std::string> possible_answers = { final_years[random_number], final_years[1 + random_number], final_years[2 + random_number], final_years[3 + random_number] }; 
    // I initialized a vector like an array with all the 4 answers, including the correct one (since C++11)
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
    it = possible_answers.begin();
    std::random_shuffle(possible_answers.begin(), possible_answers.end()); //shuffled its contents 
    for (it = possible_answers.begin(); it < possible_answers.end(); it++) //some tinkering to output vector's content
        std::cout <<"\n" << *it;
```

Now the randomly generated numbers are displayed in a random order on the screen, but the correct answer is always the first generated number.